# Console properties are not showing in my browser console

Tags: javascript, console, developer-tools

[image]

Here I noticed something messed up in my browser console. I tried to access the ***properties*** of the specified ***JavaScript object***. But it shows ***undefined***, I don't know why this is happening. Also, check out some other browsers like Firefox and Edge. The same problem happened there.

Comment: What is your question here exactly, is it about the `undefined` that's appearing or is it about no properties being logged in the console when doing `console.dir()`?

Comment: Restart broswer

Comment: "*I tried to access the properties of the specified JavaScript object.*" - the value of the `greetings` variable is a string, not an object.